# Static route and dynamic public ip address

Tags: networking, routing, static-routes, fortigate

I was searching for this particular question for a long time. Advanced networking is not my expertise.

My company has two branches in two different countries.

Office 1:
Fortigate 200E and static public IP

Office 2:
Cisco Meraki router/FW and dynamic public IP.

I want to allow access from Office 2 to Office 1 without VPN to a particular port. I was told that I will be able to "fix" the IP of office 2 with static routing on the meraki side. Others telling me that this is impossible.

Please assist with explanation/solution.

Thank you!

Comment: If you intend to control access via IP address then you’ll need to purchase a static IP for Office 2. Otherwise, establish a site-to-site VPN, which should be the better option.

Comment: When you say "without VPN", do you mean "without having to install VPN clients on office computers" or do you mean "without any VPN-like technology whatsoever"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the problem is for the firewall on the Fortigate 200E
to accept the connection to that port from Office 2, but a firewall rule cannot
be easily created because Office 2 has no fixed IP address.

It seems to me that your options are:

1. Open that port to the entire world (not recommended!).
2. Procure a static IP for Office 2 that can be used in a firewall rule on the
   Fortigate router.
3. Based on this
   [feature request](https://forum.fortinet.com/FindPost/106493)
   from 2014, Fortigate routers do not look like supporting
   [Port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking),
   which is a mechanism whereby a dynamic IP can be white-listed on the firewall
   for a given port, but this might have changed since 2014.
   (For more explanation see
   [portknocking.org](http://portknocking.org/).)
   Check if this possibility exists for both routers on both sides.

Realistically speaking, option 2 seems the most likely to work in your case.

Comment: Whitelisting the range that the ISP for Office 2 uses should be safe enough. Never use the default port for this VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Common best practices tell us that a site-to-site VPN is the way to go. But if that isn't feasable a feature in FortiOS might help.
You can put a captive portal on the policy which accepts traffic to the particular port. Of course, this is not an option if you need non-interactive access.
But just an open port without authentication should not be an option.